# Angular $routeProvider resolve creates injector exceptions

Tags: angularjs

I've set up an controller with a corresponding resolve function

```
window.ResolveCtrl = ['$scope', 'resolvedData',
  function ($scope, resolvedData) {
    console.log("RESOLVED:", resolvedData);
  }
];

window.ResolveCtrlResolve = {
  resolvedData: ['Api', '$q', function(Api, $q) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    Api.someApiCall(function (err, data) {
      if (err) defer.reject(err);
      else defer.resolve(data);
    });
    return defer.promise;
  }]
};
```

Here is the `$routeProvider`

```
$routeProvider.when('/example', {
  templateUrl:  "partials/example.html",
  controller: 'ResolveCtrl',
  resolve: ResolveCtrlResolve
});
```

The first `console.log` correctly logs the `resolvedData` object with it's contents, however it is directly followed by an `$injector` error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: resolvedDataProvider <- resolvedData
```

Why is this happening?

UPDATE: Seems the controller constructor is called 2 times in a row, but I don't know why.

Comment: Works in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D7tSlJozC7y3ZEQ0ti9r?p=preview).

Comment: Other than that your example has nothing to do with the question because it doesn't use `resolve` anywhere, it works.

Comment: It was obviously a wrong plunker. Correct link: http://plnkr.co/edit/WSSsuV30tVG1tgZ0y3fc?p=preview

Comment: As I mentioned in the update, the controller seems to be instanciated twice - and I don't know why. There's just one `ng-controller` reference in there.

Comment: Looks to me you're using `ng-controller` to reference the `ResolveCtrl`. You shouldn't do that when `ResolveCtrl` is already referenced in the routes. When controller is referenced with `ng-controller` than that invocation is both duplicate and without knowledge of `resolvedData` injection.

Comment: Oh... yeah, seems logical.

Comment: If you had posted it as an answer I'd have accepted it.